# Cant Boot up my Ubuntu system

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, mount

I am trying to boot up my ubuntu os but apparently my /dev/sda3 journal filesystem seems to be corrupt

here is the error to be precise

```
/dev/sda3: recovering journal
/dev/sda3: clean, 1558425/2569104, 9728347/10244608
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for acrordrdc, revision 24
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for acrordrdc, revision 28
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for core, revision 10908
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for core18, revision 1988
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for core18, revision 1997
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 145
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 60
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-34-1804, revision 145
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for gtk-3-common-themes, revision 1514
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for snap-store, revision 498
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for snap-store, revision 518
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for snapd, revision 11402
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for wine-platform-3-stable, revision 10
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for wine-platform-3-stable, revision 11
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for wine-platform-runtime, revision 212
[FAILED] Failed to mount Mount unit for wine-platform-runtime, revision 2116
```

I have tried alternatives like cleaning up the filesystem using the GRUB advanced section and also via a live Ubuntu on my USB drive, but neither appears to have solved the problem.

Please how do i go about this ?

Comment: No. the file system is `clean`. What fails is mounting the several loop drives for snaps. Have you uninstalled something recently?

Comment: yes @ChanganAuto i think i tampered with the snap folder. is there a way i can fix it?

Comment: Well, that would do it... I don't know how to fix it but reinstalling certainly will :)

Comment: reinstalling ubuntu? , wouldn't i lose all my files?

Comment: No, if you have backups (or a separated /home). You should *always* have backups. There's also a way to reinstall by selecting the "something else" and then selecting all the required partitions but not tick format thus preserving the files but you should always have backups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error messages are due to a failure to mount snap volumes for installed snap packages. That indeed was due to tampering with system folders for snap. Before proceeding with a full reinstall, you could attempt whether removing and reinstalling the snaps, or, one step further, the snap daemon snap may already restore the system.

First try just removing and reinstalling all snaps. List snaps with `snap list`, remove snaps individually with `snap remove <package>`. Note that some snaps, e.g. `core` cannot be removed before removing snaps that use them, so the order of removal is important. You will see in error messages whether that is the case.

If that fails, try purging and reinstalling the entire snap system: `sudo apt remove --purge snap`, to be sure reboot at that point and then reinstall `snap`: `sudo apt install snap`, which will automatically restore the needed system files and folders.

Comment: ok thank you @vanadium, i'd try this out. I am to do this in the advanced grup section right?

Comment: i think it worked, let me just go and reinstall to be sure everything is okay. Thanks a lot !, i really appreciate it

Comment: Done!, thanks again